# mysql - using concat for the value inside one single cell

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query that should allow me to search into various columns for a specific search string.

My database as 3 columns I need to search and compare the search string with:

```
manufacturer
model
number
```

The problem I've got is that people should be allowed to search (in any order) each of this columns.

Now, I've used `concat_ws('%20',manufacturer,model,number) like '%$q%'`and it kinda works.

Let's assume I have this values into my DB columns (as they are now, no commas and no separator - they are names into my read DB, I simplified them as letters here for simplicity):

```
manufacturer: A B 
model: C D E
number: F G H
```

and I want to search for:

```
A B C D F H //this doesn't work.
A C F //this does work.
```

The problem I've got is that all of my columns can be composed by multiple, space separated, words.

How can I be able to search for each word into each column in any order?

hope this question is clear enough, please feel free to ask more details if required.

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason of using concat? You can do something like this: 
`manufacturer like '%string%' or model like '%string%' or number like '%%'`

Comment: It was because I need to be able to search for each column in any possible orfder. I've just tested you suggestion but that doesn't work either, because i'll end up with a string that contains manufacturer model number and manufacturer like '% manufacturer model number%' is empty as i'ts not in the manufacturer column like that

Comment: Can you please post the full sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the query a bit, I end up with this working solution.

I'm going to write it here in case this is useful for somebody else as well:

```
$q = $_REQUEST['search'];
$decoded = urldecode($q);
$q_array = array_filter(explode(' ', str_replace('', ' ', $decoded)));

$counter = 0;
$searchTerms = '';

foreach ($q_array as $q) {
  $counter++;
    if ($counter == 1) {
      $searchTerms .= "concat_ws(' ',manufacturer,model,number) like '%$q%'";
    } else {
      $searchTerms .= "and concat_ws(' ',manufacturer,model,number) like '%$q%'";
    }
 }



$first_query_part = "select manufacturer, model, number from table where ";    
$sql_res = $first_query_part . $searchTerms;
```

And this works.

Basically, I divide each searched word and I push them into an array, then I count the words and append `concat_ws(' ',manufacturer,model,number) like '%$q%'";` for each searched words.